# Kindle showing old app name

Tags: android

I have an app existing since a long time on market place. I'm planning to change its name in the next release. However, while running the app on kindle fire device, it keeps showing me the old app name when I install it through eclipse, even though I've changed the name in AndroidManifest.xml.

Uninstalling and then installing the app is no help. It shows the new name for a while, and reverts to the old name again. That is one hell of a stubborn device.

Has someone encountered this strange behaviour ever before, or can suggest any weird solution for this weird problem. I'm encountering this only on kindle, while its working perfectly fine on other android devices.

Comment: Clean your project and check if you don't have old name in some localized strings, this sometimes helps

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. I've changed every single instance of localized strings. Even grepped for the old name, it really exists nowhere.